# Recovering contacts from my phone

Tags: google-contacts

My boyfriends phone was stolen & all we want out of it is the contacts. The phone is currently activated & being used. Can we retrieve the contacts & put them on another phone? If so, does the new phone have to be activated first?

Answer (score 0):

Are your contacts backed up on Google account? If so, they will be automatically added to the next device you login to with the same account.

Answer (score 0):

If your boyfriend was using his Google account to store his contacts, he can access the contact information at https://contacts.google.com/

When he signs into a new android phone with his Google account, the contacts will be available.

Note: If the phone is still being used and activated, I would suggest he change his passwords, as well as report it to the carrier so the phone can be blocked.

Answer (score 0):

**Google Sync** is a valid option. If it was setup on that phone just change your password, connect to that account with new phone and in contacts menu select Import>From Google Account(s)

---

**Second option** (has nothing to do with android):

**It's not a 100% reliable way, and will depend on your mobile provider.** Take ANYTHING that might prove that the sim-card was yours: top-up receipts, the big  plastic card from the sim (with phone number,pin, puk codes, etc. written on it), if you topped up online a bank statement with those payments might also do.  Pay them a visit, explain what happened they might help you recover your contacts and if you are lucky the number as well!

Second option worked out for me once, although they did charge me a little for the contact retrieval.